# Force fill all fields when creating a new post

Tags: posts

How do I force all fields to create a new post?

If a field (such as a category or title, etc.) is not filled, an error message will be issued

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've been looking for a suitable solution for this as well. I came across this plugin which will make certain fields mandatory before a post can be published. Hope you may help with this.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/required-fields/

Comment: Thanks . this plugin is good . their problem is only Set Required Fields For Pages And Posts . you can`t set required fields for custom post type and ...

Comment: @MostafaNorzade For title of custom post type this link may help you. https://kellenmace.com/require-post-title-for-custom-post-type/